# MeteorJS: Change between many UI frameworks

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, materialize

I want to let the user change theme in my app. Is possible in meteor to selectively select what package to load? or dynamically load js/css/less? Example if they opt to used bootstrap I can just load the js/css/less of bootstrap. If they opt to used materialize I can just load the sets of js/css/less of the framework.

Comment: It would be difficult to switch between css and materialise since they use very different classes and structures. Can't imagine there's an easy way to do it. You'd have to use a lot of if else blocks

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock yes the idea is client has to select a theme so it has also different html files.

Comment: So you can just define things in different templates and use if blocks. Set the selected template as a session variable or something.

Comment: And I recommend looking at iron router's layout parameter.

Comment: But my real recommendation is not to switch between bs and materialise at all. It's too much work unless you feel it's absolutely necessary